# Cucumber-Extent Report with Adding Screenshots - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/formatter/Reporter

Tags: extentreports

Cucumber-Extent Reports works without Screenshots, but when I want screenshots in the Extent report, I get the below exception.

To make the Cucumber-Extent-Reports, I have done only configuration changes... no code changes.
In order to add the screenshots, I have added the hooks to add the screenshot API below.

pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber4-adapter</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.10</version>
    </dependency>
```

Runner Code:

```
plugin = {
                "pretty",
                "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:",
                "junit:reports/cucumber/cucumber.xml"},
        monochrome = true,
        dryRun = false)
```

Added the code for screenshots in Hooks:

```
@After(order = 1)
    public void logScenarioStatusOnFinish(Scenario scenario) throws IOException {

        if (scenario.getStatus() == Status.FAILED){
            File scrFile = driver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            File destinationPath = new File(screenShotsDirectoryLocation + File.separator +  scenario.getName() + "-" + scenario.getLine()+".jpg");
            FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, destinationPath );
            Reporter.addScreenCaptureFromPath(destinationPath.toString());
        }
    }
```

Added the last line -> `Reporter.addScreenCaptureFromPath(destinationPath.toString())`;
and it throw the below exceptions.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/formatter/Reporter
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.vimalselvam.cucumber.listener.Reporter.getCurrentStep(Reporter.java:162)
    at com.vimalselvam.cucumber.listener.Reporter.addScreenCaptureFromPath(Reporter.java:94)
    at my.com.testauto.stepdefs.Hooks.logScenarioStatusOnFinish(Hooks.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:26)
    at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:16)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:20)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaHookDefinition.execute(JavaHookDefinition.java:65)
    at cucumber.runner.HookDefinitionMatch.runStep(HookDefinitionMatch.java:16)
    at cucumber.runner.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:65)
    at cucumber.runner.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:50)
    at cucumber.runner.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:50)
    at cucumber.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:50)
    at io.cucumber.junit.PickleRunners$NoStepDescriptions.run(PickleRunners.java:146)
    at io.cucumber.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:68)
    at io.cucumber.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:23)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:142)
    at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:65)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber$RunCucumber.evaluate(Cucumber.java:172)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

I use the extent.properties file and extent-report.xml file.

Am I missing any JAR files or any configurations to enable screenshots?

Kindly advise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the version of your cucumber & extent report which you are trying to use? If it is 4 & above, then you have to remove cucumber-extentsreport and use only extentreports-cucumber4-adapter

Comment: Cucumber Version: 4.7.0
 <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: Cucumber-Extent-Report Versions are given above (part of the problem description).

Comment: I have removed the cucumber-extentsreport from pom and tested, but screenshots are still not attached to the report.

Comment: Are you still getting the same error? The above error is tied to cucumber-extentsreport jar which no longer supports cucumber v4.  Reporter class is no longer supported in v4.

Comment: Here is the adapter documentation for screenshots. http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/4/java/

Comment: There is no error now, but screenshots are still not attached to the report. Any advice on how to attach screenshots to extent report using v4

Comment: The Cucumber Extent Reports work fine with the only configuration for me. I have not done any Java code changes at Steps or Scenario level (not used -  test.pass() and test.fail()). http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/4/java/ provides examples with code changes to create the ExtentHtmlReports including creatin nodes, etc. Is there any way to use the Hook (@After or @AfterStep) and add the screenShots to the failed cases? Kindly advice. Thanks

Comment: the adapter is event driven. you have to use scenario.embed method to attach screenshots on @After hook. This will attach the screenshot at scenario level.

Answer (score 0):

Scenario.embed should work. see example below,

```
@After(order = 1)
    public void logScenarioStatusOnFinish(Scenario scenario) throws IOException {

        if (scenario.isFailed()){
            scenario.embed(driver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES),"image/png");

        }
    }
```

Comment: I have added the following code and still screenshot did not attach to the report.
 **`
   @After(order = 10)
    public void logScenarioStatusOnFinish(Scenario scenario) throws IOException {

     if(scenario.isFailed()) {
         byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) basePage.getWebDriverManager().getDriver()).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
            scenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png");
     }
    } '**

Comment: This was an issue in the earlier version of cucumber extent adapter. However this is resolved in the recent releases 1.0.10.  Link to recent changes - https://github.com/extent-framework/extentreports-cucumber4-adapter/compare/v1.0.10...master

Comment: The default report has been changed from html to spark in the recent release. Also there is extent service property for setting the default screenshot's folder. please explore and figure out. The above mentioned code should work.

Comment: https://github.com/extent-framework/extentreports-cucumber4-adapter/issues/20

Comment: I tried all possible options from the above link, but still, screenshots are not attached to the extent report.

Comment: ok. i guess the issue is still open then with recent releases. If you are ok to go with lower versions of the adapter, here is the combination that actually works in my local. Cucumber - core : 4.4.0, cucumber java 4.4.0, cucumber -junit 4.4.0, extenteports-cucumber4-adapter: 1.0.4